# Change line color in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the background color of Line 2 when button is clicked but the only thing that change is the whole background.

```js
function changeColor() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementByID("Div2").style.backgroundColor = "black";

}
```

```html
<div id="Div2">

  <div>Line 1</div>
  <div2 class="line">Line 2</div2>
  <div>Line 3</div>
  <button onclick="changeColor()">Change color</button>
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `<div2>`

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because the problem was caused by a typo: `getElementById` has a **lower-case** `d`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```html
<div id = "Div2">

<div>Line 1</div>  
<div id="line">Line 2</div>  
<div>Line 3</div>  
<button onclick="changeColor()">Change color</button>

<script>
    function changeColor(){
      var line = document.getElementById("line");
      line.style.backgroundColor = "black"; 
      line.style.color = "white";    
    }
 </script>
```

There are a few things you did wrong:

1. `div2` is not a valid HTML-Tag
2. `getElementByID()` must be `getElementById()`
3. `getElementById()` takes an `id` as parameter an returns the element with this id. So you have to give your line an id: `<div id="line">Line 2</div>`

EDIT: Added white font-color

Comment: Thanks alot I took me hours to achieve nothing, I forgot to put in the question if its possible to turn the text "Line 2" to white so that it's readable?

Comment: @ChristoFourie added the white color

Comment: @ChristoFourie If this answer was helpful to you please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid "onclick" attribute. Prefer "addEventListener" and try to make your function generic :

**HTML :**

```
<div>Line 1</div> 
<div id="div2" class="line">Line 2</div>  
<div>Line 3</div>  
<button id="btn">Change color</button>
```

**JS :**

```
// The function :    

function changeColor(idElement, color) {
    document.getElementById(idElement).style.backgroundColor = color;
}

// The listener :

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    changeColor('div2', 'red');
});
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/et2yo1ck/**

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct both html markup and js.

1. First, you need to add "id" attribute to the div (in order to able to find it using getElementById).
2. You can't use div2 tag, it is not valid.
3. Change only background of div, remove js that changes background of body.

---

```
<div>Line 1</div>  
<div id="div2" class="line">Line 2</div>  
<div>Line 3</div>  
<button onclick="changeColor()">Change color</button>

<script>
    function changeColor(){

    document.getElementById("div2").style.backgroundColor = "green";      

    }
 </script>
```

Comment: ok, I've added my explanation. Instead of mark answer as invalid (while answer actually solves your problem) - just ask for explanation. Thanks.